# java, determine if circle is inside an area

Tags: java, geometry

Hi im new to programming and im trying to code an algorithm in java to determine if a circle is in a rectangular area

I have the radius of the circle and the point in the middle of it(the center)

```
|_____________________________________________________
|   
|  
|  
|                     circle
|   
|  
|  
|  
|(0,0)________________________________________________
```

the bottom left corner represent the coordinate (0,0)

this is what I have so far but I know I have an error somewhere which I can't find

```
if (mCenter.getmX() + mRadius > width || 
    mCenter.getmY() + mRadius > height ||
    mCenter.getmX() - mRadius < 0 ||
    mCenter.getmY() - mRadius < 0) {
        return false; //not inside area
    }  
else { return true; }
```

In this code mCenter is a Point with a x and y coordinate, mRadius is the circle radius and width and height are the width/height of the area

thanks

Comment: Does your code compile? You have a missing bracket in your else block.

Comment: I find that for problems like these, it's best to start out writing each condition you want to test individually as their own bool, print them all, and then `or` them all together for the result. You can then try testing each one one at a time and see if you get the output you expect. This will let you narrow the problem down very quickly. You can then roll them up together into a single statement after you've done your tests.

Comment: Also as a general tip, if you find yourself with an `if else` block that only contains `return true` and `return false`, you can probably just return the conditional you're using for the `if else` block.

Comment: What's the error? It's good to write a little test program that runs your function on a few example cases and checks to see that the function returns the correct result. Bug hypothesis: There may be conflicting coordinate systems. Computer graphics often puts (0,0) in the upper left corner with positive Y values downwards, as convenient for lines of text. [BTW, although some programmers use a naming convention like `mX` for member variables (also known as instance variables), that convention is for inside the object -- it does not carry over to the accessor methods like `getY()`.]

Comment: 0,0 in the upper left corner? hmm I think that might be it ill try, ty  [EDIT] http://pastebin.com/wmvzMqwP , I dont understand this code but can you tell me if this code will put the (0,0) in the bottom or upper left corner and if the y are downward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't say what the symptom is, but your helpful diagram above uses the ordinary mathematical coordinate system while your posted code uses `awt.image.BufferedImage`. Swing and most 2D computer graphics systems use a different coordinate system that's more convenient for laying out content in reading order.

Per [GraphicsConfiguration#getDefaultTransform()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsConfiguration.html#getDefaultTransform%28%29):

> Coordinates in the coordinate space defined by the default
>   AffineTransform for screen and printer devices have the origin in the
>   upper left-hand corner of the target region of the device, with X
>   coordinates increasing to the right and Y coordinates increasing
>   downwards.

I think it's possible to set up a `GraphicsConfiguration` with a different transform. (I don't know how to do it.) Not so for [awt.image.BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html):

> All BufferedImage objects have an upper left corner coordinate of (0, 0).

javax.swing.SwingUtilities has coordinate conversion methods.

P.S. Calling `image.setRGB()` for each pixel will be slow compared to passing the entire image into `setRGB(int startX, int startY, int w, int h, int[] rgbArray, int offset, int scansize)` or `setData(Raster r)`. Usually a frame buffer is held in a 1-D array that's treated like a 2-D array, with `scansize` indicating the width of a scan line within this buffer.